# Why does a single quote inside a comment in an awk command cause quote marks to become unmatched?

Tags: bash, awk

Consider the following awk statement which sums the values of column 1 in a file

```
cat $1 e | awk '      {total=total+$1}   # this comment does not contain any single quote marks
                   END {printf("%.2f\n",total)}
               '
```

It works as expected.

Now let's keep the same statement, but change the comment to have a single quote mark inside

```
cat $1 e | awk '      {total=total+$1}   # don't do this 
                   END {printf("%.2f\n",total)}
               '
```

When I run this in either Mac Os or Centos, I get the following error

```
./bad_sum: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `
./bad_sum: line 2: `                  END {printf("%.2f\n",total)}'
```

It looks like awk is trying to match the quote mark in don't with the quote mark after awk and thus gets confused. But since comments are supposed to be ignored, how can this be explained?

Comment: shellcheck is your friend. It gives way better diagnostics than shell.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with awk. You cannot include a single quote inside a single quote delimited script or string in most shells (the ones considered Bourne-like or csh-like). Try `echo 'foo'bar'` and see it fail. Now try `echo 'foo\'bar'` and see it also fail. Now try `echo "foo'bar"` and `echo 'foo'\''bar'` and see if you can figure out why they succeed (and no, I'm am **not** suggesting you wrap scripts in double quotes). See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for more info.

Comment: The *in any shell* part is not true. You can do `echo 'foo''bar'` in `rc`, `es`, `akanga` or `zsh -o rcquotes`. You can do `echo 'foo\'bar'` in `fish`. `echo "foo'bar"` or `echo 'foo'\''bar'` would not work in `rc` or akanga.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the info, I've never had to use `rc`, `fish`, or `zsh`. What's the best way to group the shells that don't allow it - Bourne-compatible or something else? Or is it just random?

Comment: `zsh`, `bash`, `ksh` are Bourne-like, but not Bourne-compatible. What you state is true for Bourne-like (the `rc_quotes` option is not on by default in `zsh`) and csh-like shells (two distinct families even if ksh, bash, zsh have many features of csh). See also [How to use a special character as a normal one?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/296147)

Comment: I've updated my answer to say that now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It’s because your shell is interpreting the quotes and is interpreting the rest of the awk statement in the shell and not in awk.

Comment: Essentially, the first ' takes precedence, and therefore quotes the #. The truncated awk program is perfectly valid -- one action and a comment ending in "dont" (because the t is contiguous with the quoted part). It even gets filenames "do" and "this". On Linux bash, awk fails because it can't open a file "do", before bash fails because of the unbalanced quote.